# laravel email verification mailtrap works on localhost but doesn't work on ubuntu server digitalocean

Tags: laravel, mailtrap

I have successfully implemented email confirmation of my web app on localhost using mailtrap. However, after I deploy my web app on the ubuntu server digitalocean, every time I click on the registration confirmation link from mailtrap after registering on my web app, it fails. For example, I suppose my domain is aaa.com. When I access to it and register, I will receive a email in mailtrap such as http://aaa.com/email/verify/10?expires=1610106497&signature=51a29fa6ee0b8949d9d98d4d52800948b43761a3088e8e6be8b4b1316e3b3157 I click on that link to get verification, however, it fails. Althought email verification testing from mailtrap is successful when I run my web app on localhost.

In verification controller, the verify function is:

```
public function verify(Request $request, User $user)
{
    // ko co link valid
    if (! URL::hasValidSignature($request)) {
        \Log::info('url', URL::getFacadeAccessor());
        \Log::info('has validsignature', URL::hasValidSignature($request));
        return response()->json([
            //'status' => 'The verification link is invalid.',
            'status' => trans('verification.invalid'),
        ], 400);
    }

    if ($user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        return response()->json([
            //'status' => 'The email is already verified.',
            'status' => trans('verification.already_verified'),
        ], 400);
    }

    $user->markEmailAsVerified();

    event(new Verified($user));

    return response()->json([
        //'status' => 'Your email has been verified!',
        'status' => trans('verification.verified')
    ]);
}
```

I find that URL::hasValidSignature($request) can't verify $request URL.
Please help me. I am new in laravel and digitalocean.

Comment: what do you mean by fail? where is the error? have you checked the logs? have you check the firewall?

Comment: can we see your log file? what does it say on your log

Comment: @zeroone I deleted content from laravel.log. Then, I register on my web app to receive a email verification link form mailtrap. I click on that link  but it shows link invalid. I go back laravel.log, but it don't show anything. If I run my app on localhost, the email confirmation is actived well. I don't know why. This is the first time I deploy my web app on digitalocean.

Comment: @DeepeshThapa I register on my web app to receive a email verification link form mailtrap. I click on that link but it shows link invalid. I go back laravel.log, but it don't show anything. If I run my app on localhost, the email confirmation is actived well. I don't know why. This is the first time I deploy my web app on digitalocean

Comment: For example, my domain is aaa.com. When I access to it and register, I will receive a email in mailtrap such as http://aaa.com/email/verify/10?expires=1610106497&signature=51a29fa6ee0b8949d9d98d4d52800948b43761a3088e8e6be8b4b1316e3b3157
I click on that link to get verification, however, it fails.